# Batching in tf.Keras 2.1 -> ValueError: Error when checking input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a tf dataset on which I'm trying to implement batching in order to reduce memory load. The model works without batching, but I get OOM errors hence trying out batches.

**Dataset**

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(( (train_ids, train_masks), labels ))

>>>ds
<TensorDataset shapes: (((22500, 64), (22500, 64)), (22500,)), types: ((tf.int16, tf.int16), tf.int16)>
```

**Batching**

```
BATCH_SIZE = 4
ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
TOTAL_BATCHES = math.ceil(len(train_ids) / BATCH_SIZE)
TEST_BATCHES = TOTAL_BATCHES // 10
ds.shuffle(TOTAL_BATCHES)
print("Total Batches : ", str(TOTAL_BATCHES))
print("Test batches : ", str(TEST_BATCHES))

test_data = ds.take(TEST_BATCHES)
val_data = ds.take(TEST_BATCHES)
train_data = ds.skip(TEST_BATCHES*2)
```

**Model**

```
model = TFAlbertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('albert-base-v2', trainable=False)
input_layer = Input(shape=(64, ), dtype=tf.int32)
input_mask_layer = Input(shape=(64, ), dtype=tf.int32)
bert_layer = model([input_layer, input_mask_layer])[0]
flat_layer = Flatten() (bert_layer)
dense_output = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax') (flat_layer)

model_ = Model(inputs=[input_layer, input_mask_layer], outputs=dense_output)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3, epsilon=1e-08, clipnorm=1.0)
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')

model_.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=[metric])
```

**Summary of Model**

```
Model: "model_17"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_64 (InputLayer)           [(None, 64)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_65 (InputLayer)           [(None, 64)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_albert_for_sequence_classifi ((None, 2),)         11685122    input_64[0][0]                   
                                                                 input_65[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_18 (Flatten)            (None, 2)            0           tf_albert_for_sequence_classifica
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_17 (Dense)                (None, 45)           135         flatten_18[0][0]                 
==================================================================================================
Total params: 11,685,257
Trainable params: 135
Non-trainable params: 11,685,122
```

When I call `model_.fit(train_data, validation_data=(val_data), epochs=1, verbose=1)` with the batch I got the error:

```
        ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_66 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (None, 22500, 64)
```

I know I need to reshape my inputs but I'm not sure how.

Comment: From the code you posted for Batching, it should be `ds.shuffle(TOTAL_BATCHES)` - is that just a copy & paste error?

Comment: Aha my bad, I'll fix that thanks. I was a copy paste / edit error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by not using tensorflow datasets. It's obviously not a perfect fix, but it works for now.

With the various inputs and labels as tf tensors, I did:

```
inputs_ids = input_ids.numpy()
input_masks = input_masks.numpy()
labels = labels.numpy()
```

And then for the fit:

```
model.fit([input_ids, input_masks], labels, epochs=10, batch_size=10)
```

And batch sizing is now working and no longer getting OOM errors.